# Is it possible to deal with Enterprise Keywords using SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, enterprise-keywords

first up big ups to **You** SPFx guys supporting and building our future :-) I am just returning after 5 years IT break, and I am impressed :-)

I am currently evaluating the options for UI platforms to handle our SharePoint data. Is it possible to deal with Enterprise Keyword fields using SPFx at the current stage?If not will it be possible?
With dealing I mean:

- **New** record with an Enterprise Keywords Column, add multiple keywords, existing and new ones
- **Edit** a record with an Enterprise Keywords Column, modify keywords
- **View** a record with an Enterprise Keywords Column, list all applied keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is more a question around - do we have APIs to modify Enterprise Keywords column using remote APIs (REST/JSOM/CSOM). SharePoint Framework is more a UI level presentation framework, but we still use native API surface from the SharePoint Online.

Now - personally have not dug on this API side too much, but there seems to be at least APIs to perform this using CSOM - so in worst case scenario, you would be calling WebAPI and then call back to SPO for applying needed configuration.

Comment: Cheers, that cleared it up a bit :-)